# list or string type in this example

Tags: python

if words = "This is a SENTENCE" in this assignment statement:

```py
words = "This is a SENTENCE".split()
```

is a string, as it is double-quoted.  But why the codelens showed it is the list, see below:

[image: see here]

Comment: Please don't post images; nobody wants to follow links from anonymous sources. You should copy-paste the relevant parts of the code and output to your question.

Comment: "This is a SENTENCE" is a string, "words" is a list. You did not assign the string to words, before that, you called .split(), a method that split the words by whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"This is a SENTENCE"` is a string, however the `.split()` takes that string and returns a list (splitting it at the whitespace, hence why each element of the list is one of the words of the sentence).

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> Return a list of the words in the string

Also relevant:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.